# Нужно найти регулярное выражение по которому Laravel validation email rule валидирует email

Tags: laravel

Для создания *client side валидации* нужно найти **регулярное выражение** по которому **Laravel**  *валидирует*  **email**.

В каком файле происходит использование регулярных выражений?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем проверять email по регулярке, если есть хорошая функция [filter_var](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)?

Laravel того же мнения, и они не используют регулярку:

```
/**
 * Validate that an attribute is a valid e-mail address.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateEmail($attribute, $value)
{
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
}
```

Ссылка на сам метод: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L590